# How to observe child divs of a parent div using Mutation observer

Tags: javascript, html, css, mutation-observers

I'm trying to observe changes to a property of child divs under a parent div using mutation observer but somehow I cannot. Here is my code so far.

**index.html**:

```html
<div id="Otp_verify_errors">
  <div class="successText" id="email_success" style="display:none" aria-hidden="true" role="alert" aria-label="E-mail address verified. You can now continue.">E-mail address verified. You can now continue.</div>
  <div class="errorText error" id="email_fail_retry" style="display: inline;" aria-hidden="true" role="alert" aria-label="Code Incorrect" aria-live="polite">Code Incorrect</div>
  <div class="errorText error" id="email_fail_no_retry" style="display:none" aria-hidden="true" role="alert" aria-label="no retry available">no retry available</div>
</div>
```

**myIndex.js**: (inside the document.ready() function)

All the divs are set `aria-hidden:true` on page launch and only on button click one of the divs value is set to false so that it can be shown the webpage.

```js
const verifyErrors = document.querySelector("#Otp_verify_errors");
if (verifyErrors) {
  console.log("inside mutation if"); - > I can see this in the console
  const errorObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    console.log(`Mutations: ${mutations}`);
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      // idea is to get the id of the div where the style attribute
      // aria-hidden is set to false dynamically based on the response 
      // from API call
    });
  });

  errorObserver.observe(verifyErrors, {
    childList: true,
    attributes: true,
    subTree: true,
    characterData: true,
  });
}
```

Right now, no changes are being tracked even the style attributes are changed on button click.

Can some one help me what am I missing here?

Comment: Typo: `subTree` should be `subtree`.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for helping me out. It helped fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the problem.
Also, thanks to `@wOxxom` for helping me find bug in the code

```
const verifyErrors = document.querySelector("#Otp_verify_errors");
        if (verifyErrors) {
          const errorObserver = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
            mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
              var attrHidden = mutation.target.getAttribute("aria-hidden");
              if (attrHidden == "false") {
                console.log(mutation.target.id);
                // do whatever you want to do with the id
              }
            });
          });

          errorObserver.observe(verifyErrors, {
            childList: true,
            attributes: true,
            subtree: true,
            characterData: true,
          });
        }
```